# InputBot binding not working when I have a Slint window running in a different thread

Tags: multithreading, rust, keyboard-events

I'm using Slint to build a UI for my small Rust application and part of the functionality of the application is listening for global keyboard events so that the UI doesn't need to be in focus for it to work.

I'm using [InputBot](https://github.com/obv-mikhail/InputBot) to listen for keyboard events.

I have noticed that if I have a window open the keybindings no longer fire, even though each is running in separate threads. It doesn't make a difference which one is running in the main thread. If I comment out the window code, the events fire as expected, even if a different application is in focus.

I made a small poc to demonstrate the issue which I'll include here:

```rust
use std::{thread, sync::mpsc::{self, Receiver, Sender}};

mod data;

slint::slint!{
    import { Button } from "std-widgets.slint";

    export global MainWindowLogic {
        callback button_pressed();        
    }

    export component MainWindow inherits Window {
        Button { 
            text: "Click";
            clicked => {MainWindowLogic.button-pressed()}
         }
    }
}


fn main() {
    let (tx, rx): (Sender<String>, Receiver<String>) = mpsc::channel();
    let (dssend, dsreceive): (Sender<bool>, Receiver<bool>) = mpsc::channel();

    thread::spawn(move||{
        let mut data: data::Data = Default::default();

        loop {
            let result = rx.recv();
            println!("{} - {}", result.unwrap(), data.get_data());
        }
    });    

    //If I have this here, inputbot binding no longer works
    thread::spawn(move || {
        let main_window = MainWindow::new().unwrap();  
        main_window.global::<MainWindowLogic>().on_button_pressed(move | | 
            {            
                dssend.send(true);
            }
        );  
        main_window.run().unwrap();
    });

    inputbot::KeybdKey::NKey.bind(move|| {
        if inputbot::KeybdKey::LControlKey.is_pressed(){
            println!("{}", "PRESSED");
            tx.send(String::from("T")).unwrap();
        }
    });

    inputbot::handle_input_events();
    
}
```

Data is a basic struct as follows:

```rust
pub struct Data {
    data: i32,
}

impl Data {
    pub fn get_data(&mut self) -> i32{
        return self.data;
    }
    
}

impl Default for Data {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self { data: 1 }
    }
}
```

I'm not very experienced with Rust and I'm not sure why this doesn't work. I would appreciate it if anyone could suggest better ways to listen for global inputs or if there is something glaringly obvious I'm doing wrong.